# Python Dataframe extract quarterly data and export to a quarterly folder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have a summary dataframe. I want to extract quarterly data and export it to the quarterly folders created already.

My code:

```
ad = pd.DataFrame({"sensor_value":[10,20]},index=['2019-01-01 05:00:00','2019-06-01 05:00:00'])
ad = 
                     sensor_value
2019-01-01 05:00:00            10
2019-06-01 05:00:00            20

ad.index = pd.to_datetime(ad.index,format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# create quarter column
ad['quarter'] = ad.index.to_period('Q')
ad =
                     sensor_value quarter
2019-01-01 05:00:00            10  2019Q1
2019-06-01 05:00:00            20  2019Q2

# quarters list
qt_list = ad['quarter'].unique()

# extract data for quarter and store it in the corresponding folder that already exist
fold_location = 'C\\Data\\'
for i in qt_list:
    auxdf = ad[ad['quarter']=='%s'%(i)]
    save_loc = fold_location+'\\'+str(i)
    auxdf.to_csv(save_loc+'\\'+'Sensor_1minData_%s.csv'%(i))
```

Is there a better way of doing it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with something like:

```py
for quarter, df in ad.groupby('quarter'):
    df.to_csv(f"C\\Data\\{quarter}\\Sensor_1minData_{quarter}.csv")
```